# multiple image stitching in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-stitching

I am trying to run a code on image stitching using opencv Stitcher module on Windows.

Here is a code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

images = []

for file in glob.glob("path_to_images/*.png"):
    n= cv2.imread(file)
    images.append(n)

result = images[0]   
for i in images:
    stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)
    result = stitcher.stitch(result, images[i])
    cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/user/Desktop/mosaicing/island/out1.jpg", result[1])
```

I receive an error:
`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I would appreciate any hints on how to solve it. TIA

Comment: What is your "path_to_images"?

Comment: Your for loop is iterating over the images but you are using each image `i` as an index: `images[i]`.  Try `stitcher.stitch(result, i)`

Comment: @Evan, "path_to_images" is a path to directory where I storage images (already corrected it)

Comment: @Bill hank you for your advice.

Comment: @A.Klim If the comment was helpful, please upvote it!